# Unable to set the tags for uialertview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

This is the UIAlertView I am using setting the tag as shown

```
 UIAlertView *alertViewDelete = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"delete User"
                                                                        message:@"can't restore data after deletion"
                                                                       delegate:nil
                                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"delete"
                                                              otherButtonTitles:@"cancel", nil];
                alertViewDelete.tag = 97;
                [alertViewDelete show];
```

Using this code to read the button clicked

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView1 clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(alertView1.tag == 97)
    {
    if(buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"ok");
    }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"bye");
        }
    }
}
```

iOS application objective C ... I'm going again and again over this code, can't find where or what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: We need to know what you expect it to do, and what it's actually doing before we can help. Add in an `NSLog(@"%@", buttonIndex);` to see if the button is the one you expect. Also, this kind of thing is easier to debug if you step through with the debugger.

Comment: @jack what do you think this parameter is responsible for, why do you use nil here `delegate:nil` ?

Comment: @Almo: Placeholder of type "%@" with a primitive parameter like `NSInteger` should cause an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. %ld or wrapping the tag into a NSNumber should be a better solution.

Comment: wow, i went through this too many times, and couldn't see that delegate should be delegate:self ... thx @A-Live

Answer (score 1):

you forget two things

Add `UIAlertviewDelegate` in your viewcontroller.h

set

```
 alertViewDelete.delegate = self;
 alertViewDelete.tag = 97;
 [alertViewDelete show];
```

Answer (score 0):

From [one of WWDC '15 videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-231/): avoid tags, use references.

Which means, set your alert view as a property on your class, that way you don't depend on a random `int` to know whom you're looking for.

As for your code snippet, you're setting the `UIAlertView`s delegate to `nil`. You have to conform to the `UIAlertViewDelegate` on your class and set the delegate to `self` for that delegate method to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
UIAlertController *alertViewDelete = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Delete User" message:@"can't restore data after deletion" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
        //your NSLog
        NSLog(@"ok")
        [av dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];

    UIAlertAction *deleteUser = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Delete" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
        //your NSLog
        NSLog(@"bye")
        [av dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        // whatever method you have that deletes user
        [self deleteUser];
        // tell your application where you want it to go
        UIStoryboard *storyBoard =[ UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *vc = [storyBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
        AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        del.window.rootViewController = vc;
    }];

    [av addAction:cancel];
    [av addAction:deleteUser];
```